# Stop keyboard from popping in a Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-softkeyboard

I have an app that, in a specific view uses a custom numeric keypad. The problem is the native keyboard keeps popping in the inputs on that view. How can I prevent that? I changed the inputs to read-only, and it seems to work, but without the cursor there is no way the user will know where he is editing. My app is initially an android-only app.

I need to use the native keyboard in other views, like the login view, as the password isn't numeric only.
Is there a way to prevent the native keyboard to open in a specific view? Or if I need to leave the readonly format, how can I "mask" the css to help the user? 
I have a variable that is responsible for changing the ng-model attr value.
I thought of editing the css in the $watch of that variable, but how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

Put this inside the Activities where you don't want the keyboard to be displayed.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" ...>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm building the app in cordova, He works with web views and not an activity for each view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent keyboard show as I know, but you can simulate the behaviour.

Use [ionic keyboard plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard), and when the field is focused, just do `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();`

Comment: Hey I am having the same problem, sadly your solution doesnt really work well it works maybe 20% of the time the other 80% the Keyboard jumps up and the down like a flickering...